# Как в php heredoc сделать условие if else?

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
<?php
echo <<<HTML
<input type="checkbox" {$time ? 'checked' : ''}>
HTML;
?>
```

Синтаксис по понятным причинам не верный, нужно вот эту строчку заменить на верную

```
{$time ? 'checked' : ''}
```

Условие нужно именно в самом `heredoc`

Comment: Используйте это `{=$time ? 'checked' : ''}` - добавьте знак равно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел такое решение

```
<?php
$if = function($condition, $true, $false){
  return $condition ? $true : $false;
};

echo <<<HTML
<input type="checkbox" {$if($time, 'checked', '')}>
HTML;
?>
```